# Не исполняется js скрипт, вернувшийся от сервера Ajax

Tags: jquery, javascript

Имеется привычный Ajax (POST) запрос страницы. Вместе с HTML содержимым страницы возвращается (response) скрипт js, который не выполняется на стороне клиента:

```
<script>
//Здесь много кода
</script>
```

Comment: Слышал про eval() в js - насколько безопасно и правильно использовать?

Comment: А почему бы не вернуть какой-то признак, по которому скрипт выполняется или не выполняется?

Comment: Наверное, вы не поняли суть вопроса...

Comment: @Oleg Ponomarchuk, это русскоязычный форум.

Comment: @Oleg Ponomarchuk, и какая же она, эта суть?

Comment: Я на русском пишу языке, суть не в том, чтобы вернуть статус - выполнено, не выполнено, а выполнить жава скрипт в ответе от Ajax.

Comment: @Oleg Ponomarchuk, отвечает сервер, а аякс принимает ответ. Вы хотите после ответа сервер выполнить какой-то скрипт, который возвращает сервер, правильно? Только зачем возвращать скрипт, если можно вернуть признак выполнения/невыполнения этого скрипта? Если я чего-то не понимаю - объясните более подробно.

Comment: Ajax возвращает на странице html и js.
Html вставляется в заданный блок, в js должен выполниться

Comment: Вот я у вас и спрашиваю - возвращать js-код с сервера - принципиально? Без этого никак не обойтись? Выполнить заранее подготовленный код, например?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не знаю зачем так делать, но может автору подойдет нечто такое:

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.type='text/javascript';
script.src="script.js";
document.body.appendChild(script);
```

Есть еще вариант с document.write, но я уже не помню ничего.

Вообще вопрос довольно просто ищется по следующему запросу: динамическая подгрузка js сценариев.

Answer (score 0):

Лучше уберите теги и выполните полученный код с помощью eval(). Я так делаю, удобно. Только нужно смотреть, чтобы никаких лишних символов не было, иначе не выполнится.

Comment: Лишние теги - это <script>? Лишние символы - это переносы строк?

Answer (score 0):

From jQuery's documentation for .load():
jQuery uses the browser's `.innerHTML` property to parse the retrieved document and insert it into the current document. During this process, browsers often filter elements from the document such as `<html>`, `<title>`, or `<head>` elements.
To load scripts, you should create `<script>` elements yourself in the document's `<head>`:

```
$('<script>', {src: 'js_file.js'}).appendTo('head');Perhaps you can request a list of scripts to load from the server with ajax:
$.post('scripts_to_load.json', function (data) {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.scripts.length; i++) {
        $('<script>', {src: data.scripts[i]}).appendTo('head');
    }
});
```

Comment: Т.е. если у меня от Ajax возвращается

    response.js = "<script>alert('ok');</script>", 

тогда код будет таков:

     $('<script>', {src: response.js).appendTo('head');